# Prove convergence using limit comparison or direct comparison $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{2^n}{n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Prove that the series converge using direct comparison or limit comparison
$$\sum \limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{2^n}{n!}.$$

I really don't know how to proceed with the comparison tests though I know how to prove its convergence using ratio test.

Comment: You may use for example that $\frac{{2^n }}{{n!}} \le \frac{{16}}{{n(n + 1)}}$ for $n \ge 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is useful to notice that for an $n$ large enough:

$$\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)^{n}=\frac{2^n}{n^n}>\frac{2^n}{n!}>\frac{1}{n!}$$

After that, one might proceed by observing that:

$$\left(\frac{2}{n}\right) < \frac{4}{5} \forall n >3$$

After that, you have a simple GP sum:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{2}{n}\right)^{n} < 2 + 1 + \sum_{n=3}^{\infty} (4/5)^n$$

Clearly, RHS is convergent.

Answer (score 0):

So basically this series is taylor expansion of $e^2$.

We can prove it's convergence using Ratio test.

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2^{n+1}n!}{(n+1)!2^n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2}{n+1}=0<1$

Hence the series $\frac{2^n}{n!}$ converges.